# Provide npm packages as ES modules as-is

Tags: webpack, es6-modules

I like to use some libraries provided as npm modules (with dependencies etc.) in a web page as ES modules that does not need a build system (eg. webpack) by itself.

So I use npm and webpack to bundle these libraries into a ES module file, using package.json: "type":"module" and an index.js like:

```
import * as _FOO  from 'foo';
import {Bar as _Bar} from 'foo-bar-baz'

export let FOO=_FOO;
export let Bar=_Bar;
```

Then I import dist/main.js as ES6 module in my further code, providing all imports I need, with no need of building as far the dependencies don't change.

However, it seems silly to take care of this index.js.
So is there any way to just webpack all npm packages listed as project dependencies into an ES module with their native export names?

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't use `let` to declare an extra variable in the *index.js* module, you should just `export { _FOO as FOO }` (or `export { FOO }` if you don't alias it with the underscore) and `export { Bar } from 'foo-bar-baz'`.

Comment: "*with their native export names*" - `export * from 'foo-bar-baz';` does that. It should be trivial to write a plugin that reads your *package.json* and dynamically generates an *index.js* with all these `export` declarations.

Comment: Ah ok, using just export without import.. so we are down to one line per package. Cool.

Comment: I just imagined what if ES6 modules where there before node / npm was. Most likely, there would be a strong resistance against introducing JS build systems at all, and the dependency hell we meet today maybe would have never took off.